# Serializing a list of objects with django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer/), I can serialize a native Python object like this:

```
class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
serializer.data

# --> {'email': 'leila@example.com', 'content': 'foo bar', 'created': '2016-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}
```

Is it possible to do the same for a list of objects using [`ListSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can simply add many=True for serialising list.

```
comments = [Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar'),
            Comment(email='leila1@example.com', content='foo bar 1'),
            Comment(email='leila2@example.com', content='foo bar 2')]
serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
serializer.data
```

Comment: And how to un-serialize a list?

Comment: many=True is what I was looking for over an hour

Comment: List serializer not validating the object, if I remove many=True and run an empty single object it gets validated for required fields. for the list, it is always 200 for an empty list.

Comment: I was missing many=True again