# How can I get separated queryset with value as list?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm refactoring django application with rest-framework. I tried to return post with comments, and the application work with this.

It's my json design, and I can't change models. But I can change json design.

```
{
    "id": 1
    "title": "Title",
    "content": "Content",
    ...,
    "comments": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "parent": 0,
                "content": "Content",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent": 1,
                "content": "Content",
                ...
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parent": 0,
                "content": "Content",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "parent": 3,
                "content": "Content",
                ...
            },
        ],
    ],
    ...
}
```

In comments, there are many lists which grouped by "group" column. In that case, data seems like this.

```py
Comment(id=1, parent=0, content="Content", group=1)
Comment(id=2, parent=1, content="Content", group=1)
Comment(id=3, parent=0, content="Content", group=2)
Comment(id=4, parent=3, content="Content", group=2)
```

I want to get queryset separated by `group` column. And I want to use like this.

```py
comments = Comment.objects.filter() # How can I get?
# [[Comment(id=1), Comment(id=2)], [Comment(id=3), Comment(id=4)]]
serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
```

I refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398477/serializing-a-list-of-objects-with-django-rest-framework) that how can I use serializer with list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how this can be done in database query. But i am pretty hopeful following code can solve your problem.

```
comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-group') 
# now we have <Comment(id=1), Comment(id=2), Comment(id=3), Comment(id=4)> as query_set
```

Now we are going to separate list by group number and merge them in response. As like

```
response = []
current_group = [] # this will add in repose separated by group number
previous_group = -1 # assign anything that can't be a group number

for comment in comments: 
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
    if serializer.data['group'] == previous_group:
       current_group.append(serializer.data)
    else:
        if previous_group != -1: # our previous assign value
           response.append(current_group)
           current_group = []
           current_group.append(serializer.data)
           previous_group = serializer.data['group']
        else:   # first value
           current_group.append(serializer.data)
           previous_group = serializer.data['group']

# check current_group list length
if len(current_group) > 0:
   response.append(current_group)
```

Now our response array will be like

```
[[Comment(id=1), Comment(id=2)], [Comment(id=3), Comment(id=4)]]
```

Then return response array.