# How to serialize a list of model instances?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a list of Lexemes. I need to serialize it (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398477/serializing-a-list-of-objects-with-django-rest-framework)):

```py
lexemes = [Lexeme('a', 'b', 'c'), Lexeme('d', 'e', 'f')]
serializer = LexemeSerializer(data=lexemes, many=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    return Response(serializer.validated_data)
else:
    return Response(
        serializer.errors,
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )
```

My responce is

> [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Lexeme."]},{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Lexeme."]}]

```py
class Lexeme(models.Model):
    lemma = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    part_of_speech = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    endings = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class LexemeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lexeme
        fields = '__all__'
```

The difference between my code and code from referenced question I'm using model serializer. Is it the cause of error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `ModelSerializer` accepts a list of instances with `many=True` option.

As `data` argument to `serializer = LexemeSerializer(data=lexemes, many=True)`, you need to pass a `queryset`.